# Change the spacing between lines of section title

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing

I changed the fontsize of my section title using the following code:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                                  {-2ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -2ex}%
                                  {1ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                  {\normalfont\fontsize{10}{20}\bfseries}}
```

which does the work. However it keeps the spacing (between the lines of the section title, I used two columns article) that I had with the default fontsize. Does anyone know how I can adapt the code to change the spacing?

Comment: I minimal example I set up with your redefinition has a line-spacing of `20pt`. You must be doing something else then. Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: thanks for the tip Kurt! also awkwardly I had forgotten the 20 in
`\normalfont\fontsize{10}{20}` was for specifying the spacing, so i fixed my issue through that remark Werner! sorry about that!